# bayes rule question regarding exam performance related

Tags: bayes-theorem

In an exam, there is a problem that $60\%$ of students know the correct answer. However, there is $15\%$ chance that a student picked the wrong answer even if he/she knows it and there is also a $25\%$ chance that a student does not know the answer but guessed it correctly. If a student did get the problem right, what is the chance that this student really knows the answer?

Comment: P(A1|B) = 0.6*0.15/(0.6*0.15)+(0.4*0.25) = 0.47

Comment: Don't pick figures randomly. Think a bit. See the hint in answer

Comment: You were on the right track except for picking wrong figures.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

A = knows answer, B = answers correctly

$P(A\cap B)$ = $0.6\times 0.85$

$P(A^c\cap B)$ = $0.4\times 0.25$ 
**$$P(A|B) = \frac{(0.6\times 0.85)}{(0.6\times 0.85) + (0.4\times 0.25)} = 0.8361$$**

Comment: P(A|B) = 0.6*0.51/(0.60*0.51)+(0.4*0.1) = 0.884

Comment: From *where* did you get 0.51 and 0.1 ? Anyway, I have now answered with correct figures. Note that 15% of students who knew the answers got it *wrong*, so 85% got it *right*.

Comment: Is it right:  P(A|B) = 0.60*(1-0.15)/(0.6*(1-0.15))+(0.4*(1-0.75)) = 0.836

Comment: Sorry,I just missunderstand a bit

Comment: Yes, but the last term should simply be written as  0.4*0.25

Answer (score -1):

In an exam, there is a problem that 60% of students know the correct answer. However, there is 15% chance that a student picked the wrong answer even if he/she knows it and there is also a 25% chance that a student does not know the answer but guessed it correctly. If a student did get the problem right, what is the chance that this student really knows the answer?